# Configuración de SQL Server Compact en Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Buen día.

Estoy intentando entender el funcionamiento de las plataformas **.NET** y para esto me descarge la suite de **Visual Studio 2015** y me he leído(visto) algunos *tuto´s*.
La verdad estoy comenzando y tengo unas pequeñas dudas comparado al almacenamiento local. 
Me he dado cuenta que hay varias formas de hacer almacenamiento local, pero me encante por una base de datos compacta de **SQL Server**. 
Mi primera falla fue al no encontrar en esta suite el paquete ya instalado, por eso siguiendo instrucciones fui a la pagina de *MSN*, descargue el instalador para 64bits y lo instale, cree una tabla de prueba y comencé a hacer el código de conexión.
En un modulo coloque lo siguiente:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe
Module conexion
    'Public con As New SqlCeConnection("Data Source='C:\Users\vmix\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\clienteTaquilla\clienteTaquilla\datos.sdf'")

    Public Sub conectarese()

        Dim conn As SqlCeConnection = Nothing

        Try
            conn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\Users\pc\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\clienteTaquilla\clienteTaquilla\datos.sdf")
            conn.Open()

            Dim cmd As SqlCeCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers ([Customer ID], [Company Name]) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')"

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Finally
            conn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub
End Module
```

Luego en un formulario coloque este código:

```
    Public Class login

    Private Sub textClave_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles textClave.TextChanged, textDominio.TextChanged, textUsuario.TextChanged
        botonLogin.Enabled = ((textUsuario.TextLength > 0) And (textClave.TextLength > 0) And (textDominio.TextLength > 0))

    End Sub

    Private Sub login_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        conectarese()
        MsgBox("ddsd")

        'Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM acceso"
        'Dim da As New SqlCeCommand(sql, con)
        'Dim dt As New DataTable("Acceso")
        'da.Fill(dt)
        textDominio.Text = "ddsf"
        Me.botonLogin.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

El detalle esta que cuando ejecuto el código, no me da una excepción de la que estaba esperando(creo que es porque no es una librería nativa) pero no se me ejecuta el código después de llegar a cierta linea

```
conn = New SqlCeConnection("Data Source=C:\Users\vmix\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\clienteTaquilla\clienteTaquilla\datos.sdf")
```

Justamente en ese punto da el error, y me he leído bastante bien la documentación y estoy llamando al archivo de la *Base de Datos* como se debería llamar.
En el cuadro *ventana inmediata* veo esto:

```
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.ArgumentException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.NullReferenceException' en clienteTaquilla.exe
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.NullReferenceException' en clienteTaquilla.exe
Excepción producida: 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' en System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
Excepción producida: 'System.NullReferenceException' en clienteTaquilla.exe
```

Lo que me parece es que por algún motivo no se carga bien la librería.
En las referencias del proyecto esta `System.Data.SqlServerCe` pero al intentar ir al formulario, seleccionar un `comboBox`, dar click en *elegir elementos* veo elementos `SQL` pero no `SqlCe` que son los que debería mostrarme.
Si alguien tiene alguna solución o me da alguna luz sobre lo que puede estar pasando, se lo agradecería.

Comment: como primer paso, debes importar la libreria en cada formulario que vayas a usar. La referencia es general al proyecto.

Comment: La pregunta esta medio confusa, no logro darme cuenta cual es tu error especifico.

Comment: Tienes razon @gbianchi
en el codigo llamo a las librerias pero se me ponen en gris Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlServerCe no se porque se me ponen en ese color.

Comment: La verdad no esta muy claro el error, pero por lo que se alcanza a visualizar, estas pasando un valor null a alguno de los constructores de SqlServerCe. Te recomiendo que hagas Debug y revisa que los objetos que estas asignando no sean null.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez me disculpo por no saber mostrar los errores como son, la verdad es primera vez que trabajo con esta suite y todo lo que he hecho es con documentacion para principiantes. me documentare con respecto al modo debug, si tienes algun material que me de luz de como aplica esto(detectar los errores en modo debug) te lo agradeceria.

Comment: Bueno, revisar el código mientras se esté ejecutando es muy simple. Abres el archivo al que quieres hacerle seguimiento y con el mouse das un click en la barra lateral izquierda justo sobre la línea en la que quieres empezar a revisar (queda un punto rojo). Luego ejecutas la aplicación y debe parar justo en ese punto. Con F10 vas pasando línea por línea.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez eso lo hice anteriormente, pero no se detiene. estuve leyendo sobre eso y dice que como es un  componente externo de visual estudio, no maneja las excepciones de la misma forma. cuando llamo al proyecto, al formulario inicial primero llamo a la funcion conectarse y luego un msgbox. el msgbox no se ejecuta, solo se ejecuta el formulario. y no se ejecuta porque en la linea de conexion  a la base de datos en la funcion conectarse, muere la ejecucion. no da ningun error, lo ejecuto paso a paso y no da el error.

Comment: @WeimarYamitMorenoPerez solo se detiene la ejecucion y da el error que coloque en el post inicial. incluso al ejecutar el codigo(que no se ejecuta completo) le doy en el tab "lista de erorres" y me dice, errores:0, advertencias:0 y mensajes:0